# SQL Group dates by day of week and get count

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, group-by

I have a table with a bunch of dates in it and I need to convert those dates to what day of the week it is and then group them.

Example output looks like

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Count |
+------------+-------+
| 11/12/2018 |     1 |
| 11/19/2018 |     2 |
| 11/20/2018 |     1 |
| 11/21/2018 |     2 |
+------------+-------+
```

The output that I would like would be

```
+-----------+-------+
|  DayName  | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| Monday    |     3 |
| Tuesday   |     1 |
| Wednesday |     2 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Im just unsure on how to rename the dates to the day of the week and have them group together.

Comment: Have you look at the reference docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: [DATENAME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`datename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to extract the weekday "name":

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date), COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date)
```